# Alternatives to window-width to find window's width

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to know how many characters I can fit in a single line, but the function `window-width` returns the same number regardless of the font size. Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem with `window-width`? It does take the font size into account. If you change the font size while retaining the size of the window, it will return a different value.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior here. After changing the font size, I get the same results.

Comment: do want to get it programmatically? and @Lindydancer knor has a reply for you, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no such thing as "how many characters I can fit in a single line" since a single line may contain characters using different fonts or different sizes, and also because of the fact that fonts can be proportional so even with a single font, the size of each char can change (and beyond that, there could be kerning issues, etc...).

Comment: In a broad perspective, I agree, but with a single monospace font for the entire buffer, there is such a thing.

Comment: Of course, while the general question is ill-defined, there are many special forms of this question which are well defined.  So: what are you trying to do?

Comment: this: https://github.com/konr/widgets - I fail to stick the overlay to the right because (window-width) returns the wrong value, when I resize the font (via C-+ or C--)

Comment: You probably can't do it well with current Emacs primitives.  But you might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and request features to do that.  It could look like "find the display (pixel) width of a particular chunk of text" which you can then use to compute the right `:align-to` value for the display space property.  Tho maybe it'd be easier to add the feature to "align to the right", since there's already code to do that for R2L paragraphs.